# How to fix error: Intellisense is unable to determine the accuracy of this completion item

Tags: javascript, asp.net, d3.js, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I'm using D3.js in an asp.net core application using Visual Studio 2019.

D3 itself works, I can create SVG charts that work as expected.
However, the intellisense for D3 when using Razor does not work.

I get the following error message,

> Intellisense is unable to determine the accuracy of this completion
>   item

I made sure intellisese is enabled.
I have tried using referencing the D3 library locally or using a link to the CDN.

I have seen some things on this topic on previous version of Visual studio regarding a _reference.js file but that doesn't apply in vs2019.

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I am running  Visual Studio 2019 v16.3.2, my D3 project was created when v16.3.0 was latest.

The intellisense in fresh projects created in v16.3.2 works perfectly even though there was nothing in the release notes that indicated any intellisense fix in Javascript.

In the end, I created a fresh new Visual Studio solution and imported my old project file by file.
I did not change a line of code or change any setting. The only difference between the two solutions is that the old one was created when v16.3.0 was latest (and upgraded to v16.3.2) and the new one when v16.3.2 is latest.

This is more of a workaround than an answer but I wasted too many hours on this and had to move on.

Comment: Hi lan, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, just a reminder :)